Ubuntu not booting on Thinkpad L460
I have a Lenovo Thinkpad L460 and I use ventoy to install Ubuntu on it, when I turn on my laptop it shows the menu where you select the boot device and when I click the ssd the screen goes black for a few secs and it just goes back to the boot device select screen. I've tried messing with the boot device order and the uefi/bios boot options.

Please provide the version of ubuntu. In addition try another tool to create an image or use Linux to install the iso file to an usb stick with the dd command

Some Lenovos have a boot lock. Check UEFI settings. Lenovo T450 Problem with boot repair GRUB - Boot Lock issue
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2494747
Lenovo Locked UEFI/BIOS setting:
https://www.reddit.com/media?url=https%3A%2F%2Fi.redd.it%2Foygxuo193ui41.jpg
